# Replace all "?" with "\\?" in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

is it possible to replace all the questionmarks ("?") with "\?" ?

Lets say I have a  String, and I want to delete some parts of that String, one part with an URL in it. Like this:

```
String longstring = "..."; //This is the long String
String replacestring = "http://test.com/awesomeness.asp?page=27";
longstring.replaceAll(replacestring, "");
```

But! As I understand it you can't use the replaceAll() method with a String that contains one single questionmark, you have to make them like this "\?" first.

So the question is; Is there some way to replace questionmarks with "\?" in a String? And no, I'm able to just change the String.

Thanks in advance, hope someone understands me! (Sorry for bad English...)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Don't use `replaceAll()`, use `replace()`!

It is a common misconception that `replaceAll()` replaces *all* occurrences and `replace()` just replaces one or something. This is totally incorrect.

`replaceAll()` is poorly named - it actually replaces a *regex*.
`replace()` replaces simple Strings, which is what you want.

Both methods replace **all** occurrences of the target.

Just do this:

```
longstring = longstring.replace(replacestring, "");
```

And it will all work.

Comment: +1 for `common misconception` part.

Comment: the javadoc indicates for replace(CharSequence, CharSequence): Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence.

Comment: @Elloco and your point is???

Comment: I finally split the string by "?" and rebuild the string replacing "?"(s) I want ...

Answer (score 4):

Escape the `\` too, using `\\\\?`.

```
String longstring = "..."; //This is the long String
String replacestring = "http://test.com/awesomeness.asp?page=27";
longstring=longstring.replaceAll(replacestring, "\\\\?");
```

But as other answer have mentioned, `replaceAll` is a bit overkill, just a `replace` should work.

Comment: This actually works, but instead of "\\\?" you must have "\\\\?". But as Bohemian and the other guys said; I'll use replace() instead. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`String.replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) instead of [`String.replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

```
longstring = longstring.replace("?", "\\?");
```

[`String.replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) uses [Regular Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), while [`String.replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) uses plain text.

Answer (score 2):

`replaceAll` takes a regular expression, and `?` has a special meaning in the regex world.

You should use [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) in this case, since you don't need a regex.

```
String longstring = "..."; //This is the long String
String replacestring = "http://test.com/awesomeness.asp?page=27";
longstring = longstring.replace(replacestring, "");
```

---

Oh, and strings are immutable!! `longstring = longstring.replace(..)`, notice the assignment.

Comment: String s = s.replace("?",null);